# Visual Studio doesn't recognize std library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, std

I'm writing an MFC application on Visual Studio 2015 in C++. I added some code which uses members of std library and suppose to take an int and create from it a hex char* with the prefix "0x". I tried to build the project on VS 2015 and VS 2017 from two different computers and I get the same errors - VS doesn't recognize the std library. I've tied running the code on other programs (Clion) and it worked well.

When I include `#include <stdlib>` I get the following error:
`cannot open source file "stdlib"`

I've tried re-installing VS, and checked I have all the necessary extensions to support C++, but I guess there's still something missing. How can I fix it?

The code:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
int i = 7;

ss << std::hex << std::showbase << i;
std::string str = ss.str();
const char *output = str.c_str();

std::cout << output << std::endl;
```

and included the following headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <strstream>
```

I get the following errors:

```
'Ostringstream': is not a member of 'std'
'Ostringstream': undeclared identifier
'ss': undeclared identifier
'hex': is not a member of 'std'
'showbase': is not a member of 'std'
'string': is not a member of 'std'
'string': undeclared identifier
```

Thank you.

Comment: C++ is case sensitive `Ostringstream` should be `ostringstream`

Comment: Can you get "Hello world!" working?

Comment: @george `stdlib.h` is a c header, `cstdlib` is for c++, `stdlib` doesn't exist in either

Comment: If Visual Studio had such problems, people would have realized it 20 years ago. Errors like these occur when a project's include and library paths are wrong. How did you create that project? Have you tried creating a *new* project and compiling it? Just a simple console app would do.

Comment: @AlanBirtles In my code I've used `ostringstream` with small letter

Comment: @Bathsheba you're right, when I open new console app project, I can't even run simple 'Hello world' program. what can cause it?

Comment: @user14092875: Can you replace your example code with the "Hello world!" program?

Comment: your error message says otherwise...

Comment: @Bathsheba I've tried to reproduce the error - but the second time I've built it and pressed on run it worked. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.
.

Comment: @AlanBritles, you're right but I've checked my code again (and you can also see in the code lines I've added) and ostringstream is written in small letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've included the headers in the wrong order. In every C++ project in Visual Studio it includes `"stdafx.h"` library automatically. This library contains many of the commonly used libraries such as `<string>` and etc. The solution was to write the includes in the following way:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
// other headers of the form "header.h"

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <strstream>
// other headers of the form <header>
```

instead of:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <strstream>
// other headers of the form <header>

#include "stdafx.h"
// other headers of the form "header.h"
```

a bit more about this in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234311/include-stdafx-h-in-header-or-source-file)

Thanks for everyone who tried to help, I appreciate your time and attention.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: @BarrnetChou I will make sure to mark it as an answer as soon as I will be able to. unfortunately, for some reason (perhaps because I'm new) I can mark it as an answer only 24 hours after I've published it.